# Can i disable / unbind javascript events triggered from a plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetimepicker

I was hoping for a good suggestion on how to remove/unbind events bound from a plugin. I am using a plugin that includes a javascript function for scrolling on overflow. Unfortunately, this also captures the wheel, such that the window cannot scroll.
I am therefore interested in a way to disable/remove/unbind the wheel event which I can do in the browser. Any good suggestions?

[image]

Comment: you can only remove an event listener if it's a named function and you know what the name is. If it's coming from a plugin, it's probably not a globally named function.

Comment: However, if it's a jQuery binding, you can use `$(element).off("wheel")` to remove all  jQuery event handlers for that event.